# .NET or ActiveX component for playing common video formats

Tags: .net, video, directshow, playback, directshow.net

I'm looking for any reliable, commercial or freeware component to add video playback support in .NET application.

Tried numerous options and packages and none of them seem to handle playback of common formats.

The most common option - Windows Media Player ActiveX - is quite good, but requires WMPlayer to be installed on user's machine.

MediaFoundation doesn't seem to work on XP.

DirectX AudioVideoPlayback API is very buggy. It works perfectly on one machine or completely fails on another (with the same codecs being installed).

Something SIMPLE and RELIABLE would be great. I've also tried FFOSX which claims to support the required functionality. While it works perfectly in VB6, it completely crashes in .NET environment.

It's really confusing that everything works partially or doesn't work at all.

Any suggestions regarding possible alternatives I haven't tested so far would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried silverlight? there are MANY silverlight media players available--free and commercial.

Comment: WMP is available on any Windows version since at least XP.  Except in the N edition in the EU and the K and KN editions in Korea.  They forced Microsoft to unbundle it.  That's something you put in the readme.txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [VLC (VideoLan Client)](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)? It is a self-contained, open source media player that you can use in .net applications as an [ActiveX control](http://wiki.videolan.org/ActiveX). You will need to verify the license though, but I think it is safe to redistribute the official binaries.